# See changes applied to specified lines of code in a specified Git commit?

Tags: git

I am currently analysing a Git repo, and am trying to find out how code injected in a certain commit may evolve over time in subsequent commits. For example, given line 9 in commit 57176a..., what is the next commit in the master branch that modifies this line of code?

As far as I know `git log` and `git blame` work in the other direction: They can analyse a line in a given commit based on **previous** commits. However, what I would like to do is analyse a line in a given commit based on **subsequent** commits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `--reverse` option for [`git blame`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) can help you.  If you run this:

```
git blame -L 9,9 --reverse 57176a..master your_file_name
```

git will start from the specified commit and search forward in the history until line 9 changes.  The output will show you the last commit in which the line was unchanged.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this gives what the original poster is asking for. The documentation says "this shows the last revision in which a line has existed", which seems to mean it shows you the very last commit, instead of the subsequent one, if I'm reading and test this correctly. So I'm not actually sure if you can "walk the history forward" with this, it seems to just take you all the way to the end. I'll need to test some more later to confirm.

Comment: Git works by lines; if a commit changes a line, then git sees it as the line being removed and replaced by a different line, and `git blame --reverse` will show you the commit's parent.